# Sort an associative array In ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How to sort this array by age in ascending order

```
var employ = [
    {"id":1, "name":"Andrew", "age":30, "gender":"m", "category":"G"},
    {"id":2, "name":"Brandon", "age":25, "gender":"m", "category":"G"},
    {"id":3, "name":"Christine", "age":20, "gender":"m", "category":"G"},
    {"id":4, "name":"Elena", "age":29, "gender":"W", "category":"M"}   
    ];`
```

**Desired output is:**

```
var employ = [
{"id":3, "name":"Christine", "age":20, "gender":"m", "category":"G"},
{"id":2, "name":"Brandon", "age":25, "gender":"m", "category":"G"},
{"id":4, "name":"Elena", "age":29, "gender":"W", "category":"M"},
{"id":1, "name":"Andrew", "age":30, "gender":"m", "category":"G"}
        ];
```

I tried using **employ.sort()** but i doesn't get the desired output.

Comment: Please share expected output and your attempt.

Comment: age should be in descending order

Comment: so, sort by age in descending order?

Comment: What have you tried already? We're here to help when you have issues, not do it for you.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: if choice[0] = A and age is maximum then pop {"id":4, "name":"Elena", "age":29, "gender":"W", "category":"M","choice":["E","C","D","A","B"]}  and keep it in a separate array.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the code that you tried

Comment: i used var max = Math.max.apply(null,
                        Object.keys(data).map(function(e) {
                                return e+"--"+ data[e][1]+"--"+ data[e]["age"];
                        })); but the output is NaN

Answer (score 0):

You could get first the maximum age and then filter by age and if `choice` contains the wanted value.

```js
var employ = [{ id: 1, name: "Andrew", age: 30, gender: "m", category: "G", choice: ["A", "C", "D", "B", "E"] }, { id: 2, name: "Brandon", age: 25, gender: "m", category: "G", choice: ["A", "C", "D", "E", "B"] }, { id: 3, name: "Christine", age: 20, gender: "m", category: "G", choice: ["A", "E", "D", "B", "C"] }, { id: 4, name: "Elena", age: 29, gender: "W", category: "M", choice: ["E", "C", "D", "A", "B"] }],
    maxAge = Math.max(...employ.map(({ age }) => age)),
    result = employ.filter(({ age, choice }) => age === maxAge && choice.includes('A'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```